# How to return a value from Closure into a method

Tags: groovy

I'm obviously doing it wrong but isn't it possible for callPrint() to use the return value from the closure? How can I correctly pass the return value of a Closure into a method?

```
void callPrint(def num){
    println "${num}";
}

callPrint{return 5}; //does not print
```

Thanks.

Regards,
John

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to pass a [`closure`](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Closures) to `callPrint` method and actually call it inside it:

```
void callPrint(closure){
    println closure.call()
}

callPrint{return 5}

def hello = { return 'Hello' }

callPrint(hello)
```

It prints:

```
5
Hello
```

Comment: or `void callPrint( Closure c ) { println c() }`